# What timestamp is 81 40 91 27

Tags: timestamp

What time and date is 81 40 91 27?
This number was taken from the 'firstinstalldatetime' registry key in Windows98, as I am trying to figure out the exact time and date that windows98 was installed.
As far as I know, this number is a bitmask, but I am having trouble converting it to a readable date and time.

Comment: Do you know *about* when that version of Windows 98 was installed? The closest "sensible" date I've found is "Wednesday, April 22, 2009 3:28:25pm", but that still seems far too recent!

Comment: Well, I did put 98 on a clean hard drive from a back-up image off of a dvd, but that was before 2009. I would think the registry entry would retain the original install date.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a unix time stamp, Can't know for sure tho.

> The unix time stamp is a way to track time as a running total of seconds. This count starts at the Unix Epoch on January 1st, 1970 at UTC. Therefore, the unix time stamp is merely the number of seconds between a particular date and the Unix Epoch. It should also be pointed out (thanks to the comments from visitors to this site) that this point in time technically does not change no matter where you are located on the globe. This is very useful to computer systems for tracking and sorting dated information in dynamic and distributed applications both online and client side.

If you remove the spaces, you will get: `Mon, 31 Jul 1972 05:38:47 GMT`

Comment: Yeah, haha :) All I know for sure is that the latest date would be no later than in 2001.